# Query Excel Formula: =IF(MONTH(Data!B:B)=2,COUNTIF(Data!O:O,"*HE (Technical)*"),0)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to summarise data I have in a table into months Jan,Feb,Mar etc, and need to separate the counts of various strings (such as `HE(Technical)`).

Some context: column "B" of my Data sheet are dates (not necessarily in chronological order), column "O" are keywords/strings.

I want to sort all instances of a particular string by the month based on the dates inputted in column "B".

May I know how I would go about this?
My current formula (in title) only returns zeroes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be much easier to help you if you provide some sample data and your expectec output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working with an `=IF(...,CountIf())` construction, you might try to work with a `=CountIfS()` formula (the `IfS` gives the opportunity to combine criteria.

For example, I have tried the following formula and the result was quite promising:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B3,2,O1:O3,"*HE*")
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you @Dominque, I initially started off using COUNTIFS; but had trouble using the MONTH function to call out data; I understand it should be MONTH(date) to return a value, but in this instance I want to pull out dates with JAN or 1 (for example) in the DD/MM/YYYY format. 

May I ask what the criteria type "2" set in your formula means? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you were checking `Month(B:B)`, I just thought you were checking `B:B` itself. You might create a helper column, containing `=Month(B:B)` and using my formula on that helper column.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've managed to get it to work using the helper column. Learned something new today :)